# Integrate Skype into Messaging Menu

Tags: skype, messaging-menu

I know Skype is proprietary, but it would be awesome if it were to be integrated into messaging menu much like Pidgin, Empathy, etc. Is there a plug-in that does that?

Answer (score 7):

> How to add Skype to the Ubuntu
>   Messaging Menu:
>
> 1. Install Skype : http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/
> 2. Download and install the .deb package @ http://ubuntuone.com/p/nl1/
> 3. Run the commands below in a Terminal to place a shortcut to Skype
>      in the Messaging even when its not
>      running (just like ‘Chat’ or
>      ‘Broadcast’):
>
> `mkdir -p ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications/ && cp /usr/share/skype-wrapper/skype ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications/skype`
>
> Remove Skype from the systray
>   whitelist by entering the following
>   command into a Terminal or Alt-F2
>   dialog: –
>
> `gsettings set
>   com.canonical.Unity.Panel
>   systray-whitelist
>   &quot;['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble',
>   'Wine', 'hp-systray']`
>
> Log out/Log in Click the Messaging
>   Menu icon, Click Skype. You will be
>   promoted to ‘allow’ permission  for
>   the menu entry to work as intended.
>
> [image]

[Source: OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/how-to-add-and-control-skype-via-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu/)

Comment: I found this to be very buggy. See comments from source post.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the "Skype API Plugin for Pidgin/libpurple/Adium"by Eion Robb at http://eion.robbmob.com/

Comment: I use skype4pidgin too, it works great :)