# How to integrate Skype into the messaging menu?

Tags: 10.10, skype, messaging-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Integrate Skype into Messaging Menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41815/integrate-skype-into-messaging-menu)

I saw in the latest release of PinguyOS that somehow they had skype under the messaging menu. It looked something like this:

[image]

How did they do this? Right now I have Empathy under the Messaging Menu and skype seperately on the notification area but I'd like to move Skype also under the Messaging Menu just like in that picture... How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [how-to on OMGUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/how-to-add-and-control-skype-via-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu/) to do exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Looks good, but ONE problem.... Since that was probably for 11.04 and Unity, this script that is supposed to remove skype icon from system tray doesn't work.... "gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'hp-systray']""

How do I remove skype icon from system tray now...?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, that was for 11.04 and since they are phasing it out it's not hard to hide things.  I've been looking and haven't been able to find a way to hide a icon in the notification are in the 10.10 panel.  I know some other panels (xfce panel) and docks (awn) have that capability. Other than replacing your panel the only thing I can think of right now would be asking the Mint developer.  I'll keep looking and post back if I find anything else.

Comment: And coincidentally, WebUpd8 just did an article on this today (http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/skype-ubuntu-messaging-menu-notifyosd.html) with some variations, but again no mention on removing the icon from the notification area on 10.10

Answer (score 0):

You use the indicator-applet-skype script.

See [its project page on GitHub](https://github.com/andreashappe/indicator-applet-skype) or [here](https://github.com/andreashappe/indicator-applet-skype/raw/master/indicator-applet-skype.py) for a direct link to the script.

Comment: How do Ι run this script? 


queenz@martin-maverick:~/Desktop$ python indicator-applet-skype.py 
  File "indicator-applet-skype.py", line 6
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Seems like you downloaded the html-version. Try running `wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/andreashappe/indicator-applet-skype/raw/master/indicator-applet-skype.py` in a terminal.